# Different Footer on each Page of a Word Document (QR Code tagging)

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, qr-code

My goal is to tag documents by encoding their unique identifier as well as the page number on each page (preferably in the footer) using a QR code - this way documents can be scanned in any order. I generate the QR code in Python using zbar and return the path of the resulting PNG to VBA. I then insert the QR code into the document footer, but I am having trouble inserting a different QR code into each page.

This is surprisingly difficult - it seems as though perhaps I am misusing the footer. Would it be possible to insert the QR code into the margin/background of the document?

Comment: Not at all a big Word user, but I think all pages in the same Section share the same footer.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/delete-or-change-a-header-or-footer-on-a-single-page-a9b6c963-a3e1-4de1-9142-ca1be1dba7ff and https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1274722

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word 2013 & later can generate QR barcodes without the need for 3rd-party products, via the DISPLAYBARCODE field. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh745901(v=office.12).aspx. Provided you know how to incorporate the page # into the character string used for the barcode, you can obtain that via a PAGE field, thus leveraging Word's ability to generate a different code on each page.

Otherwise, you'll need to:

• insert a Next Page Section break between each page that is not already separated via such a Section break;

• ensure each new Section that you create does not use either the "different first page" or "different odd & even" page layout;

• unlink the footer from the previous Section;

• delete any unwanted content from the footer (if you add the barcodes as you go, this will include the barcode you added to the previous footer); and

• only after you have done the above, add you barcodes to the Section's footer.

As you can see, it is quite an involved process if you can't use Word's DISPLAYBARCODE field.

Comment: An alternative to modifying the document's structure so drastically if you can't use Word's DISPLAYBARCODE field would be to insert the images into the body of the document on each page then reposition them as floating shapes in the footer area.